# проверка соответствия строчных значений одной ячейки в другой ячейке pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Номер': ['1000', '2000', '3000', '4000', '5000', '6000', '7000'],
                   'Ключ': [1000_2, 1000_3, 3000_1, 3000_6, 5000_8, 6000_7, 8000_9],
                   })
```

Пробую проверить, входит ли значение ячеек 'Номер' в соответствующую ячейку 'Ключ':

Все значения перевел в строковый тип.

```
df = df.astype('str')

df['Ключ'].str.contains(df_BSSI['Номер позиции'])
```

и выдается ошибка: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'.`

Проверка на соответствие проходит:

```
Positions = df['Номер позиции'].tolist()
Keys = df['Ключ'].tolist()

lst = []
for i in range(len(Positions)):
    if Positions[i] in Keys[i]:
        lst.append(1)
    else:
        lst.append(0)

print(lst)
```

Результат:

```
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Но хотелось бы с помощью pandas выполнить такую проверку.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом в `str.contains()` можно передать не конкретное значение, а значение соседней ячейки?
Или, возможно, есть другой способ проверить это соответствие?
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В метод `str.contains` нужно передавать подстроку, а не серию, как это делаете вы. можете воспользоваться методом `apply`, например:

```
res = df["Номер"].apply(lambda x: df["Ключ"].astype(str).str.contains(x))
```

вы получите матрицу сравнения *каждого* значения в одной колонке с *каждым* в другой.

res:

```
       0      1      2      3      4      5      6
0   True   True  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
2  False  False   True   True  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
4  False  False  False  False   True  False  False
5  False  False  False  False  False   True  False
6  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
```

Если вам нужно сравнить значения *построчно*, то сделать можно так:

```
df = df.astype(str)
res1 = df.apply(lambda x: x["Номер"]in x ["Ключ"], axis=1)
```

res1:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Разделите столбец `’Ключ’` по разделителю `_` на два.
2. Проверьте на равенство первый полученный столбец с `‘Номер’`.

Answer (score 0):

Если брать за основу приведенный фрейм с исходными типами данных, то можно привести номер к целому числу, а ключ поделить целочисленно на 10, затем сравнить

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Номер': ['1000', '2000', '3000', '4000', '5000', '6000', '7000'],
                   'Ключ': [1000_2, 1000_3, 3000_1, 3000_6, 5000_8, 6000_7, 8000_9]})
df['Входит'] = df['Номер'].astype(int).eq(df['Ключ'].div(10).astype(int)).astype(int)
print(df)
```

```
  Номер   Ключ  Входит
0  1000  10002       1
1  2000  10003       0
2  3000  30001       1
3  4000  30006       0
4  5000  50008       1
5  6000  60007       1
6  7000  80009       0
```